# How can I use environmental variable for database password in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to hide my database password by using .env file. But it seems like compiler doesn't recognize where the password is..

You can see the environmental variable, PWD, which is for database password.
`.env` code.

```
PWD = 0000
SECRET  = mySecret
```

and in server.js, you can see I use dotenv module and set the config.

`server.js` code.

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const expressSanitizer = require("express-sanitizer");
const router = require("./Routes/router");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.use(router);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening to port ${port}`);
});
```

Finally, the problem here..
you can see the argument, `process.env.PWD`.
and I logged it to check what it is actually. It was not `0000`, but was `D://github/practice` which is just project directory path..

and I am not understanding what's going on!
also the I could see

`console.log(process.env.PWD);` works two times. when I run `server.js`!

`router.js` code.

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

console.log(process.env.PWD);

const sequelize = new Sequelize("vehicle", "root", process.env.PWD, {
  host: "localhost",
  port: "3306",
  dialect: "mysql",
  logging: false,
  define: {
    createdAt: false,
    timestamps: false,
  },
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

And the following is an error when I run the codes.

```
AccessDeniedError [SequelizeAccessDeniedError]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at ConnectionManager.connect (E:\github\practice\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:118:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5) {
  name: 'SequelizeAccessDeniedError',
  parent: Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
      at Packet.asError (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:712:17)
      at ClientHandshake.execute (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:425:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:209:13)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10) {
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
  },
  original: Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
      at Packet.asError (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:712:17)
      at ClientHandshake.execute (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:425:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\github\practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:209:13)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10) {
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
  }
}
```

Also, If there is a better solution to hide the database password, please let me know..!
thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a very important and **KEY** line of code

```
dotenv.config({ path: "YOUR-PATH-TO-.ENV-FILE" });
```

right after your

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

you need to provide the dotenv a path to the file which contains the ENV_VARs
as per the code you shared you can do it 2 way

### OPTION 1

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "YOUR-PATH-TO-.ENV-FILE" });
```

### OPTION 2

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: "YOUR-PATH-TO-.ENV-FILE" );
```

Comment: Hi! thanks, can you check my edited question ?

Comment: Well, since you did not pass the location of the .env file to the config option it is trying to find the .env file in its current / working dir which in your case is "D://github/practice" that is why the first issue occured, 
for the console.log() running 2 times that could be Sequelize trying to rerun the line of code above it

Comment: You are right...! my two model files are importing that db.js file..

Comment: I found that specifically the word, `PWD`, for environmental variable name doesn't work. If I use different variable names then it would just work. only `PWD` doesn't work.

Comment: Here is a Bookmark for using Env Var that i usual refer to when in doubt for naming convention
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Comment: General note on "PWD". The PWD environment variable usually represents the current working directory on Linux systems.